# Touchpad on linux way too slow

Tags: linux, touchpad, dell-inspiron

Recently my touchpad has gotten to be way too sow on Linux. I use Fedora with a Dell Inspiron 15R. It was working fine for months, but recently is unbearably slow regardless of my speed settings. I used to make it across the screen with a quick drag but now it seems like there is a 1:1 ratio between distance traveled on touchpad and how my cursor moves.

Does anyone know what could solve this?
**EDIT**

I would just like to say that this question is solved. If anyone else is having similar problems, the following command seems to have fixed it after a restart.
`sudo yum --enablerepo updates-testing update xorg-*`

Comment: Did you check touchpad pointer speed settings?

Comment: Yes, I did. It appears to be part of a recent update that is causing this, but I don't know how to tell which one or how to remove it.

There were bug reports just yesterday about similar problems by others.

Answer (score 0):

I would just like to say that this question is solved. If anyone else is having similar problems, the following command seems to have fixed it after a restart. sudo yum --enablerepo updates-testing update xorg-*

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand your answer, [here's the bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1104789), and there's also another workaround that doesn't involve enabling repos:

```
yum downgrade xorg-x11-server-Xorg xorg-x11-server-common
```

And just wait until `xorg-x11-server-1.14.4-11` is pushed to the `stable` repos.